# Infinite sum of a series $\frac{N}{100} .( \frac{99}{100})^{(N-1)}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, geometric-series

What is the sum of the following series?

$$\sum_{N=1}^\infty\frac{N}{100} \cdot\left(\frac{99}{100}\right)^{N-1}$$?

This looks like a geometric series but I think the infinite sum formula wouldn't work here as there's an $\frac{N}{100}$ in front of the series?

I think the series converges to $100$, but I'm not sure how to get there

Comment: Welcome to this site! Here is a comment to get you started. It's actually easier to forget about the $99/100$ and look at the function $f$ defined by $$f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty n x^{n-1}$$ (what you want is the number $\frac{1}{100}f(99/100)$; but *functions* are often nicer to manipulate than numbers, since then you can use calculus, etc.). Now, consider $g$ defined by $$g(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^n$$ (1) Can you compute a nicer expression for $g(x)$? (2) Can you find a way to relate $f$ and $g$ (think: differentiation)? (3) Can you use that to get a nicer expression for $f(x)$?

Comment: Equivalent questions have been asked and answered here many times.